# Row Type Update Strategy - Informatica Power Center

Tags: etl, informatica-powercenter

I have a problem in the transformation mapping for Update Strategy.

I have the transformation depending if it comes in the ' CHANGE_TYPE ' field will then updated , inserted or deleted.

But the review is a field called << ROW TYPE >>  does not correspond to the transformation

[PowerCenter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pjgn3.png)

[PowerCenter 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4v8C.png)

Comment: Side note: The way you use DECODE is not quite right. It should begin like DECODE(TRUE, CHANGE_TYPE='U', DD_UPDATE... Try to fix that before issues will come up ;)
Check http://www.howtointegratedata.com/decode-in-informatica/ to learn more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the session's properties at the Workflow level.  In Workflow Manager, edit the session, under the "Properties" tab, find the row **Treat source rows as**, and be sure you have set the value to **Data Driven**.
If it hasn't been set to Data Driven, then the Integration Service will not follow your directions in the Update Strategy expression.

[Properties tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JODm.png)

Comment: Thank you, besides what you mentioned parameterized in the database had not created the PK in the tables +1